# Filling a 2D Array with user input (integer to binary)

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have to take a user input of integers from a range, convert that to binary, and fill a 3x3 array with the binary. The only problem is, my code is giving me an output of only dependent on the first 3 numbers of that binary (i.e 010001101 = 010 across all rows).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HW11P02 { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number between 0 and 511: ");
        int n = in.nextInt();


        String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(n);
        binary = binary.format("%09d", Integer.parseInt(binary));
        System.out.println(binary);

        listArray(binary);


    };

    public static String[][] listArray(String binary) {
        String[][] array = new String[3][3];

        char ch = ' ';
        String value = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
                ch = binary.charAt(n);
                value = Character.toString(ch);
                array[i][n] = value;
                System.out.print(array[i][n] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }



        return array;
    }
};
```

Comment: You have to remember that this will not gonna print leading 0's in binary if there is no need to: ex: number 2 is gonna be: 10, because there is no need to use more than 2 bits. Enter number 255 and repost me what you get as a result.

Comment: @Slay29 my results were 0 1 1 across all 3 rows

Comment: Try using long instead normal int. Is there any difference?

Comment: @Slay29 tested it, still the same output.

Comment: I suggest you learn some debugging skills. Use a debugger to step through your code and examine the values of variables. This will let you see exactly what your code is doing and where your logic may be incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will provide the the output you may really want.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class HW11P02 
{

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a number between 0 and 511: ");
    int n = in.nextInt();

    String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(n);
    binary = binary.format("%09d", Integer.parseInt(binary));
    System.out.println(binary);

    int result[][]=new int[3][3];
    int position=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < result.length; j++)
        {
            result[i][j]=binary.charAt(position++)-'0';
            System.out.print(result[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }


}
```

}